# c++ error: incomplete type is not allowed

Tags: c++11, compiler-errors

[Errors Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfmdG.png) I want to rebuild the RplidarCpp.dll file and add some functions to it. I created the project in visual studio 2010. But there are some errors that I can't fix. Please help me to solving them.

thank you very much

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "rplidar.h"
#include <iostream>

#define _DLLEXPORT __declspec(dllexport)

using namespace rp::standalone::rplidar;

class LidarMgr
{
public:
    LidarMgr() ;
    ~LidarMgr();

    const LidarMgr& operator=(const LidarMgr&) = delete;
    const LidarMgr(const LidarMgr &) = delete;

public:
    static RPlidarDriver * lidar_drv;
    bool m_isConnected;
    rplidar_response_device_info_t devinfo;
```

the errors occur in below lines:

```
const LidarMgr& operator=(const LidarMgr&) = delete;
const LidarMgr(const LidarMgr &) = delete;
```

Top code is not complete.

Comment: So, where is the error?

Comment: Kindly update your post with the error message.

Comment: I add a picture from errors. Please see it.

Comment: You put const in front of your copy constructor

Comment: This was in original code that i downloaded. What to write?

Comment: Simply remove the `const`? The syntax for a copy constructor can be seen [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor). Perhaps there is something I'm missing. However, according to the standard, there is no such syntax for copy constructors. I believe that's the problem. Also, please post the error in text format. Pictures might turn out broken links in some future.

Comment: Thank you. those errors disappeared. but new errors appeared in the same two lines. syntax error: ';' and unexpected tokens preceding ';'